# Pool.map function in multiprocessing issue

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, numba

I have an issue with the "pool.map" function in my code. The significant part of my code is as following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(4)
list_of_as = range(200)

def run_test(a):    
    df = classA.method1(a)
    condition = classA.method2(a)
    if condition:
        in_position = classA.method3(a)
        
def run():
    p = tuple(pool.map(run_test, list_of_as))
    return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    #schedule.every(1).seconds.do(run)
    run()
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time of the loop: {(end-start)/60} minutes")
```

I call some methods of a given class that i have in another file, then, **to speed up my  code**, i do multiprocessing in a separate function. In the `run_test` function that i call in `run`, i use pandas dataframes plus some very heavy computation and api calls.
When `condition == True`, `classA.method3(a)` function is executed and `in_position` becomes `True`. At this stage, when `condition` is satisfied, **I want to pause all the other processes and keep going with only the one that satisfied the condition until `in_position` becomes `False`**.

My **second issue is the following error that i have when i run the code**:

```
  File "/home/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'run_test' on <module '__main__' from '/home/md/miniconda3/git/simulate/sim_4/run.py'>
```

- The second issue is optional because it seems that it doesn't really block the code from running, however solving the first issue is very important to me!

P.S. (The complete version of the program runs with scheduling)

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool.map` is not meant to be much more complicated than the builtin function `map`, and it seems like you need significantly different functionality. I would start off with the `Process` class, and use something like an `mp.Event` to signal the other processes should exit.

Comment: For your second issue, it seems like the function `run_test` is not defined inside wherever `run` is defined (from the traceback this seems to be `run.py`). You need to define `run_test` inside `run.py`.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments ! My second issue is solved, i just had to include the significant part of my code into an ```if __name__ == "__main__"```. As for the first part, it's still unclear how can I solve it.